# try to fetch and read the response body as json or fallback to plain text

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, browser, fetch

I'm trying to fetch data from the server, and I want to try to resolve the response body as json, if failed return it as plain text

```
fetch(`/devapi/${url}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: new Headers({
      Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
    }),
  })
    .then((res) =>
      res
        .json()
        .then((res) => res?.body?.data || res?.body || res)
        .catch((err) => res.text())
    )

    .then((val) => console.log(val));
```

when the response is **NOT** a valid json, ten `res.text()` is called, but it seems that calling `.text()` after `.json` causes an error

```
 Failed to execute 'text' on 'Response': body stream already read
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could [clone the response](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/clone), and then use it in error handler:

Try this:

```
fetch(`/devapi/${url}`, {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: new Headers({
      Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`,
    }),
  })
    .then((res) => {
      const clone = res.clone();
      return res
        .json()
        .then((res) => res?.body?.data || res?.body || res)
        .catch((err) => clone.text())
   })
    .then((val) => console.log(val));
```

or use XHR and process response in a `try/catch`:

```
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', `/devapi/${url}`, true);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem("token")}`);
xhr.onload = function() {
    let res;
    try {
        res = JSON.parse(xhr.response);
    } catch (err) {
        res = xhr.responseText;
    }
    console.log(res);
};
xhr.send();
```

Comment: nice idea, though it has some performance impact

Comment: @Sheldeeb true, in that case, maybe replace `fetch` with good ole XHR, and parse response as JSON in try/catch

Comment: @Sheldeeb I've added XHR example